# Parameter naming using System.Data.Common

Tags: c#, database

This is probably an oldie-but-goodie. I am using System.Data.Common for an interchangeable Oracle/SQL Server/SQLite data access library. During the constructor I take the connection string name and use that to determine the underlying provider type. The reason I do this is to handle the different IDbParameter naming conventions for each provider. For example, Oracle likes :parameter whereas SQL Server and SQLite like @parameter. The default is ? to cover Oledb.

Question: Is this all unnecessary and is there some simple thing I'm missing that should simply take care of this? If my IDbCommand.CommandText = "select id, name from my.table where id = :id" am I covered? For now I'm just adopting ? as the default and then RegEx'ing my way to the right parameter identifier before executing the command.

Thanks.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RelationalGateway"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>You must pass in the name of the connection string from the application configuration
    /// file rather than the connection string itself so that the class can determine
    /// which data provider to use, e.g., SqlClient vs. OracleClient.</remarks>
    public RelationalGateway(string connectionStringName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionStringName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("connectionStringName");
        if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName] == null ||
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString.Length == 0 ||
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ProviderName.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                                                    "The configuration file does not contain the {0} connection ",
                                                    connectionStringName) +
                                                "string configuration section or the section contains empty values. Please ensure the " +
                                                "configuration file has the appropriate values and try again.");
        }

        _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
        _providerName = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ProviderName;
        _theProvider = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_providerName);
        _adapter = _theProvider.CreateDataAdapter();
        //GetConnection();
        DetermineProviderSpecificParameters();
    }
```

The DetermineProviderSpecificParameters bit basically figures out "?" or ":" or "@" or something else.

UPDATE
Here's how I'm handling the details thus far:

1. Get the right parameter string:

   private void DetermineProviderSpecificParameters()
       {
           // Check for supported providers. This is so that parametized queries to limit
           // by spatial extent are correctly created.
           string shortName = _providerName.Substring(_providerName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);

   ```
       switch (shortName)
       {
           case "SqlClient":
               _param = "@";
               _ql = "[";
               _qr = "]";
               break;
           case "SQLite":
               _param = "@";
               _ql = string.Empty;
               _qr = string.Empty;
               break;
           case "OracleClient":
               _param = ":";
               _ql = string.Empty;
               _qr = string.Empty;
               break;
           default:
               _param = "?";
               _ql = string.Empty;
               _qr = string.Empty;
               break;
       }
   }
   ```
2. call a little helper before I execute each command to "cleanify" or "parameterific" it or however we call this half-assed hack:

   ```
   private void MakeProviderSpecific(IDbCommand command)
   {
       foreach (IDataParameter param in command.Parameters)
       {
           param.ParameterName = GetProviderSpecificCommandText(param.ParameterName);
       }
       command.CommandText = GetProviderSpecificCommandText(command.CommandText);
   }
   ```
3. And this calls a little regex to do to do:

   ```
   public string GetProviderSpecificCommandText(string rawCommandText)
   {
       return Regex.Replace(rawCommandText, @"\B\?\w+", new MatchEvaluator(SpecificParam));
   }
   ```

Yuck. Still searching for a relatively simple solution but the advice thus far is certainly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but one option to do what you're looking at doing is NHibernate.

Comment: I'm using NHibernate for other projects but this is a utility library for my other devs to use that gives them a quick-but-not-too-dirty Db access approach. Plus I use this as the core of my code for clients who are anti-open source. Yep, I hand roll data access code more times than I can to think about! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this for [Salamanca](http://salamanca.codeplex.com/) : see [ParameterBuilder.cs](http://salamanca.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/24649?projectName=salamanca#183762). This code uses :

- protected methods on [`DbCommandBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.aspx), called via reflection (will only work in full trust mode, I assume) : [`GetParameterPlaceholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getparameterplaceholder.aspx) and [`GetParameterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getparametername.aspx).
- the information returned by [`DbConnection.GetSchema`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.getschema.aspx). In a perfect world, I could only use this, but I failed to see how so far...

The thing is that you need a valid name for your parameter (`"@name"` in Sql Server, `"name"` in Oracle), and a valid placeholder in your SQL query (`"@name"` in Sql Server, `":name"` in Oracle).

1. With a proper connection, [`GetParameterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getparametername.aspx) will give you a valid name for your parameter.
2. Create your placeholder :

   - Either via [`GetParameterPlaceholder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.getparameterplaceholder.aspx).
   - Or query the [`DbMetaDataColumnNames.ParameterMarkerFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbmetadatacolumnnames.parametermarkerformat.aspx) value contained in [the schema for your connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254501.aspx) . You should be able to create your placeholder by using this string as a format string, taking the previous parameter name as input (implying that the format string is `"{0}"` for Sql Server and `":{0}"` for Oracle) :

     ```
     // DbConnection connection;
     // string parameterName
     DataRow schema=connection.GetSchema(DbMetaDataCollectionNames.DataSourceInformation).Rows[0];
     string placeholder=string.Format(
         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
         (string)schema[DbMetaDataColumnNames.ParameterMarkerFormat],
         name.Substring(0, Math.Min(parameterName.Length, (int)schema[DbMetaDataColumnNames.ParameterNameMaxLength]))
     );
     ```

This has been tested with Sql Server, Access, Sqlite and Oracle (but note that, quite unsurprisingly, [this will not work as is with ODP .NET](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?forumID=146&threadID=423300)...).

Comment: Thanks, Mac. That seems to answer my question. I'll take a deeper look at the Salamanca code for some other tips too. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there's no convention or API for this. ORMs such as nhibernate also implements their own mapping of the placeholder prefix for each driver.

Comment: Actually that's where I got my current implementation approach from. I'll post a bit more code so you can see what I'm doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a slight performance hit and use the [System.Data.OleDb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.aspx) classes.  That way, you could use the same code regardless of the database.  Or you could use an Inversion of Control framework like [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity).  You could then require that your data access class be injected with the appropriate factory for the database, parameters and such that the caller desires to use.

Comment: That is an option. However I would much rather avoid an IoC framework for something that I consider a utility class - just too involved for my junior devs, let alone my clients (consulting limits my options a bit).